# Can not draw according to the exact position of mouse cursor

Tags: javascript

I have found out that if i don't give canvas width and height via window.innerWidth/innerHeight line is drawn far above the actual mouse cursor. I mean I can not afford to give the canvas the whole width and height of the window. I mean there should be other divs, paragraphs etc . here I give width and height to my canvas 400px and 768px respectively. it is not behaving as it should be. I mean when I try to draw a line it appears far above my mouse cursor. How can I fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Game Stage</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var i=0;
var radius=10;

var lines;
var x,y;
var now_draw=false;
var i=0;
    function loadCanvas(id) {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        div = document.getElementById(id); 
        canvas.id     = "CursorLayer";
        canvas.width  = 400;
        canvas.height = 768;
        canvas.style.zIndex   = 8;
        canvas.style.position = "absolute";
        canvas.style.border   = "1px solid";
        div.appendChild(canvas)
    }
    function nowdraw(e){

now_draw=true;

}
function drawit(e){

if(now_draw){

var ctx=document.getElementById("CursorLayer").getContext("2d");
x=e.clientX;
y=e.clientY;
if(i==0){
ctx.lineWidth=2*radius;
ctx.lineTo(x,y);
ctx.stroke();

}
if(i>0){

ctx.fillStyle="red";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x,y,radius,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
i=0;

}
ctx.fillStyle="red";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x,y,radius,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
ctx.lineWidth=2*radius;
ctx.strokeStyle="red";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x,y);
}

}
function cannotdraw(){
now_draw=false;
i++;

}

window.onmousedown=nowdraw;
window.onmousemove=drawit;
window.onmouseup=cannotdraw;
        </script>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>draw here</h1>


<div id="divControls"></div>
<div id="divGameStage"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    loadCanvas("divGameStage");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

fiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4BXB6/)

Comment: Note that `mousemove` event handlers are expensive. Better add and remove them when needed instead of using the boolean `now_draw`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
x = e.offsetX || e.layerX || 0;
y = e.offsetY || e.layerY || 0;
```

instead of

```
x = e.clientX;
y = e.clientY;
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4BXB6/2/)

Comment: x = e.offsetX || e.layerX || 0;
y = e.offsetY || e.layerY || 0; it works.but what it actually mean ? there are three options.which one will trigger when?can you explain it?

Comment: @user3138436 [`offsetX`](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#dom-mouseevent-offsetx) and [`offsetY`](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#dom-mouseevent-offsety) return the coordinates relatively to the target, not the viewport like `clientX` and `clientY`. But Firefox supports [`layerX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.layerX) and [`layerY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.layerY) instead.